# Passing a Structure containing an array of String and an array of Integer into a C++ DLL

Tags: c++, vb.net, arrays, marshalling, structure

I'm having problems with marshaling in VB.NET to C++, here's the code :

In the C++ DLL :

```
struct APP_PARAM
{
    int numData;
    LPCSTR *text;
    int *values;
};

int App::StartApp(APP_PARAM params)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < numLines; i++)
    {
        OutputDebugString(params.text[i]);
    }
}
```

In VB.NET :

```
  <StructLayoutAttribute(LayoutKind.Sequential)> _
  Public Structure APP_PARAM
    Public numData As Integer
    Public text As System.IntPtr
    Public values As System.IntPtr
  End Structure

  Declare Function StartApp Lib "AppSupport.dll" (ByVal params As APP_PARAM) As Integer

  Sub Main()

    Dim params As APP_PARAM
    params.numData = 3

    Dim text As String() = {"A", "B", "C"}
    Dim textHandle As GCHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(text)
    params.text = GCHandle.ToIntPtr(textHandle)

    Dim values As Integer() = {10, 20, 30}
    Dim valuesHandle As GCHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(values)
    params.values = GCHandle.ToIntPtr(heightHandle)

    StartApp(params)

    textHandle.Free()
    valuesHandle.Free()

  End Sub
```

I checked the C++ side, the output from the OutputDebugString is garbage, the text array contains random characters. What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

`GCHandle.Alloc` [*"Allocates a Normal  handle for the specified object"*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a95009h1.aspx), which *"creates a handle to a managed object ... which prevents the managed object from being collected"*.

What you're looking for is the methods from `System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal`, which allow you to do things like copy managed objects to memory accessible by unmanaged code.  Unfortunately, according to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0szztey7%28VS.80%29.aspx), the pointers in your struct make it a little harder to marshal than many other things (in the sense that many other things can be automatically marshalled using the appropriate P/Invoke attributes), but it's still possible.  I've tried this out and it works:

```
APP_PARAM param = new APP_PARAM();
string[] text = new string[] { "A", "B", "C" };
param.numData = text.Length;

// Manually allocate an array of pointers, one for each string.  arr holds the array's address.
IntPtr arr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(IntPtr)) * text.Length);
try
{
  param.text = arr;

  IntPtr[] unmanagedText = new IntPtr[text.Length];
  try
  {
    // Create a null-terminated ANSI string in unmanaged memory for each element in text.
    for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
      unmanagedText[i] = Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi(text[i]);
    // Copy the addresses of the unmanaged strings into the manually allocated array.
    // I don't know of any way to make an unmanaged copy of a managed array in one call.
    Marshal.Copy(unmanagedText, 0, arr, unmanagedText.Length);

    // param now looks like what the C++ code is expecting (except for the array of int).
    StartApp(param);
  }
  finally
  {
    foreach (IntPtr str in unmanagedText)
      Marshal.FreeHGlobal(str);
  }
}
finally
{
  Marshal.FreeHGlobal(arr);
}
```

You'll have to have similar allocation/free code for your array of int values, with its own try/finally blocks to make sure FreeHGlobal is called.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use one of the methods from the `Marshal` class.

```
Dim str As String = "Hello World"
Dim ptr as IntPtr = Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi(str)
Try
  SomePInvokeCall(ptr)
Finally
  Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr)
End Try
```